# Height of JQUERY Popup Window

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery popup, which I have scripted as follows.

```
<style>
    .ui-widget-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000;
        opacity: 0.7;
        z-index: 0;
    }

</style>

var wWidth = $(window).width();
        var dWidth = wWidth * 0.85;
        var wHeight = $(window).height();
        var dHeight = wHeight * 0.85;
        $('#QualifyLead').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            bgiframe: false,
            modal: true,
            width: dWidth,
            height: dHeight,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            title: "Enter Qualify Lead Information",
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            }
        });

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function (evt, args) {
        var wWidth = $(window).width();
        var dWidth = wWidth * 0.85;
        var wHeight = $(window).height();
        var dHeight = wHeight * 0.85;
        $('#QualifyLead').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            bgiframe: false,
            modal: true,
            width: dWidth,
            height: dHeight,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            title: "Enter Qualify Lead Information",
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            }
        });
    });
```

There is a problem with this. When I have many records in my grid (**A click on the grid's button opens the popup**), I have to scroll to see the last row. When I click the button of the last row, the popup doesn't fit the height of the window. You can check the attached screenshot.

[image: Popup issue in JQuery]

What am I missing?

Comment: did your problem solved ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var wHeight = $(window).height();
```

try this:

```
var wHeight = $(window).css("height");
```